# Print layout legend item not displaying all attributes of a layer

Tags: qgis, print-composer, legend

I have created a layer of lithologies by using the Vector - Geoprocessing tools - clip function (to break down a huge file to a small file constrained by a tenement boundary).
[image]

I then go to print layout and create a legend, but the legend is not showing all of the lithology types, it is just showing one entry with the name of the clipped lithology file (EPM25886 PGN).

How do I show all of the lithologies in the legend?

If I use the larger unclipped lithology file they show up perfectly.
The colours are under a column in the attributes table called HEX.
[image]

Am a pretty new user to QGIS.

Comment: Please provide details on your layer symbology.

Comment: Layer symbology? Do you mean the fill properties? I have it set to Single symbol, simple fill, and the fill colour I had to over ride the data field (the little symbol to the right of the fill colour drop down menu) and set it to HEX otherwise all lithologies were white. I would paste a picture here, but am not sure how to sorry!

Comment: You can't display data defined colours in the legend item, you need to categorize your layer.

Comment: Ok, thanks very much for your help, I'll give that a go!